# Requesting document signing via email using template doesn't populate tab values

Tags: python, docusignapi

I have created a template with recipient and added text tabs in it, I'm using python api to send a the document using template id for signing. If I send document to the recipient attached to the template I get the document with tabs (text and checkboxes) populated but if I send it to some other email the tabs are not being populated.

What I want is to be able to send the document to any email without them being added as recipient in the template, my question is:

**Is it possible to send signing request email without adding it to template as recipient and have the tabs populated? or do I have to always add the email I'm sending signing request as recipient in the template to have the tabs populated**

here is the code

```
        radio_group = RadioGroup(
            group_name="patient_gender",
            radios=[Radio(value="Male", selected="true")]
        )

        text = Text(
            tab_label="patient_address", value="123 Main St. San Francisco, CA 94105"
        )

        text = Text(
            tab_label="patient_address", value="123 Main St. San Francisco, CA 94105"
        )

        tabs = Tabs(
            radio_group_tabs=[radio_group],
            text_tabs=[text]
        )

        signer = TemplateRole(  # The signer
            email=signer_email, name=signer_name,
            tabs=tabs,
            role_name='signer'
        )

        envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
            email_subject="Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK",
            template_id="e8886b8c-6433-4c14-963b-aed5811df098",
            template_roles=[signer],
            status="sent"  # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        )
        # Ready to go: send the envelope request
        api_client = ApiClient()
        api_client.host = base_path
        api_client.set_default_header("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)

        envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
        results = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id, envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
        return results
```

Comment: how did you define that recipient in the template? does it have an email address? if so - you should remove it and make it a "placeholder" recipient. That should fix it

Comment: also, the text tab, for example, should have a recipient_id property that should match what's in the template

Comment: @InbarGazit I defined the recipient via the UI, logged in the dev account went to templates and added template and in it I added recipient since without adding recipient I cannot place any kind of tabs on the document template.

Comment: @InbarGazit editing the recipient gives a drop down but placeholder recipient is not a listed option. Again I am doing it via the UI by logging into dev account going to template and editing the template.

Comment: so you are providing an email address for the recipient via the UI? that is not a placeholder recipient. You would want to change that. You can define a recipient that does not have an email address. that is called a placeholder and has a role name only.

Comment: @InbarGazit That actually worked! thank you for helping me out idk if I can up or accept a comment if it would be possible I would have done it! Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: I'm adding an answer. Please mark it as answered. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your template. The recipient should be a placeholder recipient, which means that recipient has no email or name, just a role name. That would allow you to provide the information from the API in real time.