# Docusign API - Setting up tabs without a recipient

Tags: c#, docusignapi

What I am trying to accomplish is an Embedded Signing workflow where a user fills out their name and email on a page, and then it pulls in a PDF for them to sign in Docusign.

I am currently using templates and tabs so that I can pre-fill information from the user in the document.

The problem I am running into is that for tabs to work it requires a recipient. I set a default recipient, and then setup my tabs.

However, when I enter a different name / email to my recipient in my form, I get a blank document with none of the tabs showing up. If I use the same combination, then my tabs (with pre-filled information) show up including the Sign Here option.

Is there a way to set up tabs or pre-filled dynamic information in Embedded Signing without having a default recipient ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See similar question on this recently - [Requesting document signing via email using template doesn't populate tab values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59669127/requesting-document-signing-via-email-using-template-doesnt-populate-tab-values?noredirect=1#comment105583921_59669127)

You need to set a placeholder recipient in your template. An empty recipient that has a role name but no email address.
You later decide the email when you create an envelope from this template.